# Redirecting from htm

Tags: redirect

My client has an old website on freeserve.co.uk (dodgy and free, now belongs to Orange but no support). I want to redirect all pages on the old site to newdomain/index.php. The index page on the old site is index.htm, however most other pages are .html.
Whatever I try the 301 redirect doesn't seem to work. Has anyone come across freeserve before?

Answer (score 0):

You want to redirect the user when they load the page, here are some [examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm).

Here's the main example

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
//-->
</script>
</head>
```

but there are a few other options depending what behaviour you're after.